tkinter not running on ubuntu
When I try to import tkinter I get the error message: Python 3.12.3 (main, May 25 2024, 22:44:21) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.



import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter/init.py", line 38, in 
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'



tkinter not working
When I try to import module tkinter the error message appears.
All the hints from the web didn't work out.

Presumably you never installed the python3-tk apt package. Try apt install python3-tk

If you built this yourself (as suggested by the /usr/local path) then check you have the development packages for tcl and tk installed. Look at the config.log from your python build to see if it found tk libraries and headers or not.

Adding to patthoyts' comment, those headers need to have been present at build time. you can't add them now and expect everything to magically work. Rebuild Python after installing them.
